# Transferring Circuit to Solderable Mini Breadboard

Tags: soldering, breadboard, nodemcu, adafruit

I have a simple wifi temp/humidity sensor I've set up on an adafruit breadboard, and I'd like to transfer to a perma-proto type board, but the solderable boards I have are a slightly different layout than the adafruit board. There do not appear to be any power rails on the edges so I'm not sure how I may need to rework the circuit for it to function. I'm very much a tinkerer/new to circuits like this so I'm trying to avoid connecting anything in a way that might damage my ESP8266.

[image: adafruit board next to solderable board]

Comment: Inline image fixed. You should use the preview below the editor to check your post before submitting.

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram.  I am not going to work it out from the picture and have no idea what your wires are two are a power supply but the others?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that solderable board is different from the breadboard. As you say, there are no power rails on it, so if you're going to use it, you need to add wires for power.

Or you can buy a board that more closely [imitates the breadboard](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12070).

Comment: wait, the picture shows a perfboard with connected rows!

Comment: @PeteBecker What are you talking about? It clearly shows there are copper traces between the holes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller -- fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Power, ground, data, and a pull-up on data, right? Skin the wires, solder in the resistor, cover the whole thing with heat-shrink.